# Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at lab_06.vhd(54) near text "shifta";

Tags: vhdl

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bl9qu.png)

Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at lab_06.vhd(54) near text "shifta";

```
Info: *******************************************************************
Info: Running Quartus II 64-Bit Analysis & Synthesis
    Info: Version 13.0.1 Build 232 06/12/2013 Service Pack 1 SJ Web Edition
    Info: Processing started: Mon Nov 13 18:53:13 2017
Info: Command: quartus_map --read_settings_files=on --write_settings_files=off lab_06 -c lab_06
Warning (20028): Parallel compilation is not licensed and has been disabled
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at lab_06.vhd(30) near text "ktj";  expecting "component"
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at lab_06.vhd(54) near text "shifta";  expecting "entity", or "architecture", or "use", or "library", or "package", or "configuration"
Info (12021): Found 0 design units, including 0 entities, in source file lab_06.vhd
Error: Quartus II 64-Bit Analysis & Synthesis was unsuccessful. 2 errors, 1 warning
    Error: Peak virtual memory: 485 megabytes
    Error: Processing ended: Mon Nov 13 18:53:14 2017
    Error: Elapsed time: 00:00:01
    Error: Total CPU time (on all processors): 00:00:01
Error (293001): Quartus II Full Compilation was unsuccessful. 4 errors, 1 warning
```

Comment: How is anyone supposed to help you when you don't provide any information on the code causing the error?

Comment: Please paste your code into the question instead of sharing an image.

Comment: my cristal ball tells me the error is in line 42.

Comment: @mfro well, the lines with error are actually specified in the little information he gives ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you've tried to instantiate `lab_06` outside the architecture `Behavior`. Had you written `end architecture Behavior;`, I think the problem would have stared you in the face.